# Why does attachment do not send with this code?

Tags: powershell

Why does attachment do not send with this code?  how do i remake this code to send email to many recipients?

```
$EmailTo = "vitaly9oleg@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "adm@forceauto.ru"
$Subject = "first letter" 
$Body = "Text of the letter" 
$SMTPServer = "mail.forceauto.ru" 
$filenameAndPath = "C:\1.txt"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("adm@forceauto.ru", "xxxx"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body,$attachment)
```

Comment: ```$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)``` could you try this and tell me the resulting error?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to handle your problem, but perhaps I can still help you with this:

In PowerShell starting from 3.0 you have a cmdlet called Send-MailMessage.

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'jesfer <jesfer@gmail.com>' -To 'tesrere<tesrere@gmail.com>' -Subject "first letter" -Body "Text of the letter" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -UseSsl
```

Regarding the credentials, it's also a parameter. But using it I'd suggest to us pscredential ob.

Edit: with Credentials

```
$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “jesfer@gmail.com”, (“s57u5t4” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Send-MailMessage -From 'jesfer <jesfer@gmail.com>' -To 'tesrere<tesrere@gmail.com>' -Subject "first letter" -Body "Text of the letter" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
```

Edit 2: with working port

```
$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “adm@forceauto.ru”, (“xxxxx” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Send-MailMessage -From 'adm <adm@forceauto.ru>' -To 'vitaly9oleg<vitaly9oleg@gmail.com>' -Subject "first letter" -Body "Text of the letter" -SmtpServer "mail.forceauto.ru" -Port 465 -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
```

Edit 3: with attachment

```
$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “adm@forceauto.ru”, (“xxxxx” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) 
Send-MailMessage -From 'adm <adm@forceauto.ru>' -To 'vitaly9oleg<vitaly9oleg@gmail.com>' -Subject "first letter" -Body "Text of the letter" -Attachments "C:\1.txt" -SmtpServer "mail.forceauto.ru" -Port 465 -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
```

Comment: @daveramsey login and password are called credentials.
Nevertheless I've updated the code. Please try it and let me know. BR

Comment: add a ```-Port 25``` to the Send-MailMessage. the STARTTTLS 3 should be coverd with the ```-useSsl``` is its enabled in the securityprotocoll settings

Comment: smtp.gmail.com 
Port 465 (SSL required)
Port 587 (TLS required)
Perhaps port 25 is not the right one?  "https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=de"

Comment: Edit 2: Did you use -Credential $$credentials? because there is a $ too much btw.
Added port of gmail smtp server

Comment: why attachment do not send with email

Comment: @daveramsey Are emails beeing send now?`
```-Attachments "C:\1.txt"```

Comment: @daveramsey Edit 3

Comment: how to send email using this code with encoding KOI8-R?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6